# auto-correlation function for a process that counts the arrival in a fixed time interval of a poisson process

Tags: probability

If Y(t) is The number of arrivals between t and t + 1 minutes, and X(t) is a Poisson process with arrival rate λ = 4 visits/minute, how can I find the auto-correlation function for Y(t)?

I have a feeling that the auto-correlation function is just $λ^2$ since $$R = E[Y(t1) Y(t2)] = E[Y(t1)] E[Y(t2)] =λ^2 $$ but here i assume the two time intervals do not overlap, since in a Poisson process the number of visits in two disjoint intervals are independent of each other. What about the case where $t2 < t1 + 1$? Would it even matter if they overlap? or is my rationale so far just completely wrong?...

Comment: Your rationale when $t_2>t_1+1$ is correct. Now to the case when $t_1<t_2<t_1+1$ (which is the core of the question), what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: I thought maybe I could split the intervals so that they are disjoint? so we get $R = [Y(t1)]E[Y(t2-t1)]=λλ(t2-t1)$? so the function starts at $0$ for $(t2-t1) = 0$ and increases linearly to $λ2$ at $(t2-t1) = 1$. However, i think my problem also partly lies in the fact that I don't really know what the autocorrelation function is about...

Comment: was suppose to mean increases linearly to $λ^2$ not $λ2$

Comment: Sure if you have no solid definition of the autocorrelation function... First thing would be to check your notes for such a definition.

Comment: okay so doing some further research the definition of auto-correlation is:  $$R(t1, t2) = C [Y(t1), Y(t2)] + E[Y(t1)]E[Y(t2)]$$ where $C$ is the auto covariance of $Y(t1$) and $Y(t2)$. Now, if I'm correct the auto co-variance is $0$ if  both random processes are independent (i.e. disjoint intervals where $t2>t1+1$). And for a Poisson process $C$ is given by (according to my professor's notes): $$C [X(t1), X(t2)] = λ min(t(1), t(2))$$ so if im on the right track $R$ should be $$R(t1, t2) = λ min(t(1), t(2)) + E[Y(t1)]E[Y(t2)]$$ im just not sure how to interpret $min(t(1), t(2))$

Comment: Sorry but you should try to be much more careful: you used $E(X_tX_s)$ for $E(Y_tY_s)$...